# IRF HP 6125G Blade Switch : determine MAC address of each member

Tags: hp, switch

I have a little problem with my HP 6125G Blade Switch. Just to precise, I don't understand much IRF configuration.

So i have a hp C7000 blade systems, with embeded blade switches (4). 
The switches are configured as an IRF stack.
2 servers and some blades are plugged on the switches (and a disk bay), all in a single VLAN.

**My problem is :** 
On my server, "someone" is sending a DHCPDISCOVER request each 7 seconds (~). Since the address MAC is mentionned in the /var/log/messages, I know it does not come from any machine (neither server nor blades), and not from the disk bay.
So it remains my IRF switches stack : when i do an arp on the management switch address, i see an @MAC that looks like a lot to the @MAC i'm looking for ; if the 4 members have almost similar @MAC, I would suspect one of them to be culprit (and because I don't have any others hardware)

**My question is :**
When connected via SSH on the switch stack, how can I check the @MAC of each member ?
I looked the configuration, as far as I understand (very far) all I can see related to mac address is the option *irf mac-address persistent timer*

Sorry if I don't use the correct terms,
any answer/advice/explanation is welcome

Thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it seems the following command ...

```
display irf
```

... displays the @MAC of each member.

In the contrary, the command

```
display irf topology
```

seems to use only the master's MAC address

Just in case, for who is interested, it seems that for each BridgeAggregation you create (in my case I use LACP) an @MAC is associated (don't know if it's a virtual one - would be another topic), you can see them with the command

```
display interface
```